# update sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have lots of rows to update according to this logic:
if in the row there is '`$$%`' then update to '`<b>$$%</b>`
exmple:

```
my name is $$997
```

need to update to

```
my name is <b>$$997</b>
```

i tried this:

```
update t_questions set qtext = replace(qtext,'$$%','<b>+$$%+</b>')
```

but doesnt work

thanks

Comment: SQL Server does not (as far as I know) have a concept of bolding text.  So if that is your intention, you'll need some other mechanism, which would typically be using a markup language of some sort.

Comment: i mean that i tried to update to this : my name is "<b>$$997</b>"

Comment: This will be much quicker and easier to do if you add a CLR function that uses regular expressions. If there is maximum one match per `qtext` instance then not too bad to do in TSQL but if there could be arbitrary number of matches this will be a pain to do

Comment: What is the logic for the end of the part that needs wrapping? Is it always `$$digits` or just until the end of the string or until a word boundary or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
update t_questions set qtext = SUBSTRING(qtext, 0, CHARINDEX('$$', qtext)) + '<b>' + SUBSTRING(qtext, CHARINDEX('$$', qtext), len(qtext)-CHARINDEX('$$', qtext)) +'</b>' where qtext like '$$%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the part you want to "bold" is everything aftering, and including, the `'$$'`, then this'll likely be easier with `STUFF`:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = STUFF(YourColumn,CHARINDEX('$$',YourColumn),0,'<b>') + '</b>'
WHERE YourColumn LIKE '%$$%';
```

`STUFF` will "insert" the string `'<b>'` in the right place, and then you can simply concatenate `'</b>'` to the end.